# How do I get back from Eve?

Tags: kerbal-space-program

I can now successfully land on Eve using a nuclear engine and several parachutes on my lander. I had originally tested taking off at Kerbin by equipping a pair of solid fuel boosters, but of course having more than twice the gravity at Eve meant this was more or less useless.

I've been looking around for an estimate of the amount of thrust/weight needed escape Eve's atmosphere but haven't found it yet. How could I go about calculating what to add to my lander given a certain weight of the lander?

Comment: [Scott Manley's Eve or Bust](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLYu7z3I8tdEmaeBwTgr9j9FTVjz8WrAbX).  Suffice it to say, taking off from Eve is difficult at best.

Comment: Also, Eve doesn't have twice the gravity that Kerbin has, but because of the combination of greater atmospheric density and higher gravity, the delta-V to orbit required is significantly higher (about 2.5 times as much).

Comment: Yeah I could tell that it was gonna be hard as soon as I tried my first time :P What would be a good approach? I'm thinking taking large pieces and connecting them in Eve's orbit then try to land it but that probably wont be very easy. There's gotta be a way...

Comment: Regarding Manley's Eve or Bust series: [Episode 13](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0EkFdyqMojg) shows the return vehicle in action. Keep in mind that you only need to get into orbit. When you managed to get so far, you can send a 2nd ship to pick them up.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[Eve](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Eve) has an atmosphere ranging all the way up to around 100,000m with surface pressure being about five times as high as on Kerbin, and almost twice as much gravity (with 16.7m/s<sup>2</sup> gravitational pull).

Depending on the height from which you're launching, you will need between ~8,000m/s and **~11,500m/s of Δv** [to achieve orbital velocity around Eve](http://wiki.kerbalspaceprogram.com/wiki/Eve#Orbital_statistics), which should give an orbital velocity of ~3,500m/s.

Eve's escape velocity is ~5,000m/s, so in order to return from a 100km Eve orbit to Kerbin, **another ~1,500m/s Δv** is required.

Comment: This, of course, largely marks *ideal* scenarios. If you miss your ascent, or don't get the transfer burns quite right you will obviously need even more fuel to correct those errors.

Comment: Wow awesome :D guess I'll start practicing and putting refueling stations in orbit. I play in career mode so there're many things I don't quite have yet but I'm gonna give it a shot.

Comment: You might need even more than 11.5km/s.  A delta-V map I looked at listed over 12km/s, and that's ideal (albeit from sea level).

Comment: @MBraedley The exact value *should* be only 11,282m/s. And as far as I recall it, there haven't been any changes to Eve's size or atmospheric parameters.

Comment: Lol kind of trivial at this stage but thanks for the details.

Comment: Yeah, I see that now.  But that's still ideal (i.e. a perfect gravity turn and ascent speed), so it'd be very hard to achieve.

Comment: @MBraedley Oh, definitely. As I said, if you miss your ascent, need to fix your circularization, or have to do any other readjustments it'll need more - way more. That said, if you're reasonably *elevated*, those 11.5km/s should get you into orbit with enough buffer.

Comment: You might need a bit less than 11.5km/s when you try to land on an elevated area. Because of the large pressure gradient, a few 1000m of height can make a large difference.

Comment: Yeah that's what I'm doing now, I landed a big rover (with four docking ports) on a mountain and have been getting giant solid fuel boosters over to it. Not the easiest thing but there are so many science reports on that rover that if I get it back I'm looking at thousands of science points (I'm playing career bridge and no mechjeb :( )

Comment: I would avoid solid rockets for Eve launches;  they have good thrust to weight (for when gaining speed is most valuable), but poor efficiency (when you need a high delta-v);  since you'll spend such a long time just slowly ascending through the lower atmosphere, solid rockets don't perform well.  focus on *staging*